# BIDS and FetchXML not returning expected results

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, bids

I have recently started working with Microsoft CRM 2011 and downloaded the CRM 2011 Developer Kit to get myself up to speed on the various aspects of CRM but I have run into a slight problem: one of the exercises has you generate a report in CRM and then download the FetchXML which is then loaded into a report within BIDS.  In CRM the query returns what I would expect (all of the contact records) but when I run the same query from within BIDS it only returns the Contact records that are loaded as sample data and not the additional contact records that I have loaded as part of the exercise.

The relevant FetchXML is:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="contact">
    <attribute name="fullname" />
    <attribute name="contoso_type" />
    <attribute name="parentcustomerid" />
    <attribute name="contactid" />
    <attribute name="contoso_lastworkoutdate" />
    <order attribute="fullname" descending="false" />
   <filter type="and">
   <filter type="or">
    <condition attribute="lastusedincampaign" operator="olderthan-x-months" value="3" />
    <condition attribute="lastusedincampaign" operator="null" />
   </filter>
   </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Is there some setting that the exercise documentation overlooked that needs to be set to download the additional contacts or am I missing something else entirely?

--- Edit ---

It is worth noting that when the RDL is uploaded back to CRM all of the data that I would expect to be in the report is there but when it is local it just contains the sample data.

Comment: Maybe it is a security issue on the server locally. Because you are using FilteredViews (I hope & presume). These are views that filter out records you don't have access to.
Maybe locally you do not have access to those specific records, but on the CRM you do.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This ended up being the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a security issue on the server locally.

Because you are using FilteredViews (I hope & presume). These are views that filter out records you don't have access to. You don't have access to those specific records locally, but on the CRM you do.